# Am I advised to install only apps with "Built for Windows 10"?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps

After I upgraded my OS to Windows 10 Mobile, am I advised to install apps which holds "Built for Windows 10" slogan? Will apps without this slogan disrupt or miss with my OS in any way? How much should I care about it before I install any app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can install all apps that are available in the store. Nothing will cause harm.

Apps that are built for Windows 10 generally launch and resume faster than Silverlight based ones, will have Windows 10 kind of UI, and **may** have Windows 10 specific features such as Interactive notification, Windows Ink, etc...